# Need to remove string leaving only the last two characters in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame which I have read from a csv file. This data have 440 rows and 900 columns. I need to focus on column one and manipulate the string to leave only 2 characters remaining in the column for each row. This data also varies in size. examples:

```
4   ADCY7_S3
5   AIMP2_S5
6   ALKBH7_S5
7   ALOX5AP_S3
```

The information I need is S1,S2,S3,S4 or S5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `substring` from `base R` if the number of characters to be extracted is 2 from the last position of each string.

```
substring(v1, nchar(v1)-1)
#[1] "S3" "S5" "S5" "S3"
```

Or with `sub` to match characters until the `_` and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub(".*_", "", v1)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("ADCY7_S3", "AIMP2_S5", "ALKBH7_S5", "ALOX5AP_S3")
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. Those work great for leaving the remaining S# value. I am finding it difficult to remove the string from each of the rows on my dataframe column. Does this require a loop to check each row index and remove the unnecessary string?

Comment: @DarrynMcCartney No, you just need to eextract the column.  Suppose `df1` is your dataframe object and `col1` is the column name `df1$col1 <- substring(df1$col1, nchar(df1$col1)-1)`